# Running xunit tests with VS: Assertion Works using Test Explorer, fails assertion with 'dotnet test'

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, assert, xunit.net

Running xunit tests with VS: Assertion Works using Test Explorer, fails assertion with 'dotnet test'. If I throw the value of the assertion, it is indeed true as expected. Advice?

I tried dotnet test and expected the test to pass. Ran with test exlporer - and it did pass

```
    [Fact]
    public void TransactionBuilderBasicTest()
    {
         MyTestsUtils.Sales.TransactionBuilder
            .AddMerchandise();

        //Assert.Equal(true, Session.ConnectedToServer);
        Assert.Equal(true, true);
    }
```

Comment: Have you run a single test in test explorer?

Comment: does commenting out the call to your stuff affect the result (might be worth editign that detail into the question)

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, in test explorer it passes. Both when running and when debugging.

Comment: @RubenBartelink Removing the assertion makes it pass

Comment: but removing or adding your code makes no difference? That's definitely not a normal situation, so something weird is going on. Out of the box we know a) xunit works in dotnet test and in IDEs b) Xunit asserts work just fine. Millions of people experience both those Just Working very day. Figuring out what's going on in your context will be a process of narrowing down the problem until it's obvious what is different about a) your environment or b) your code. All I can suggest is to start small, then keep adding bits from your larger solution until you figure out what it is.